# Why does this code blow up with a "pure virtual function call" error under Visual Studio

Tags: c++

The following code runs fine on g++ 5.1, but when run under Visual Studio 2013 or 2015, an "R6025 pure virtual function call" error occurs when `Test().GetCollection()` is called in `main()`

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class MoveNextCollection
{
    // Forward declaration
    class ConstIterator;

public:
    // Usual C++ collection typedefs
    typedef T value_type;
    typedef const value_type& const_reference;
    typedef ConstIterator const_iterator;

    const_iterator begin() const
    {
        if (MoveToStart(&_CurrentValue))
        {
            return const_iterator(this);
        }
        else
        {
            return end();
        }
    }

    const_iterator end() const
    {
        return const_iterator();
    }

    virtual ~MoveNextCollection()
    {

    }

private:

    class ConstIterator
    {
    public:
        ConstIterator(const MoveNextCollection *pMoveNextCollection = nullptr)
            : _pMoveNextCollection(pMoveNextCollection)
        {
        }

        const_reference operator*() const
        {
            return _pMoveNextCollection->GetCurrentValue();
        }

        bool operator==(const ConstIterator &iter) const
        {
            return (_pMoveNextCollection == iter._pMoveNextCollection);
        }

        bool operator!=(const ConstIterator &iter) const
        {
            return !operator==(iter);
        }

        ConstIterator &operator++()
        {
            if (!_pMoveNextCollection->MoveToNext())
            {
                _pMoveNextCollection = nullptr;
            }

            return (*this);
        }

    private:
        const MoveNextCollection *_pMoveNextCollection;
    };

    const_reference GetCurrentValue() const
    {
        return _CurrentValue;
    }

    bool MoveToNext() const
    {
        return MoveToNext(&_CurrentValue);
    }

private:
    virtual bool MoveToStart(value_type *) const = 0;
    virtual bool MoveToNext(value_type *) const = 0;

    mutable value_type _CurrentValue;
};

class Test
{
public:

    class Collection : public MoveNextCollection<int>
    {
    private:
        bool MoveToStart(int *pValue) const override
        {
            *pValue = 314; // Whatever
            return true;
        }

        bool MoveToNext(int *) const override
        {
            return false;
        }
    };

    const Collection& GetCollection() const
    {
        return _collection;
    }

private:
    Collection _collection;
};

int main()
{
    for (int val : Test().GetCollection())
    {
        std::cout << val << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This only occurs however if the virtual destructor in class "MoveNextCollection" is present. It runs fine otherwise (when the destructor is commented out). Note that the above error occurs in a desktop version of Visual Studio but if you run the code at http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/ it simply displays error -1073740791 instead (I assume it's the same error). Note that the code has been stripped down to its bare essentials for the sake of this posting (sorry, couldn't make it any shorter). Is this a VS bug? Any feedback would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do not post code links here, instead paste the critical code into your question. The process of stripping the irrelevant parts from your code either gives you a minimal example that reproduces an interesting observation, or (most likely) leads you to the solution on your own.

Comment: If that's standard policy (no posting links) will do (next time). Thanks. Note BTW that the code is stripped down to a minimum (contrived) example in order to generate the problem.

Comment: @MikeR  No, that's far from a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)!

Comment: I disagree. The code really isn't that long and while there may be room for slight improvement, this is a customized collection class being iterated in a range-based for loop. It was unclear to me exactly what was causing the problem and what I posted was the minimum necessary to make it run (and diagnose it IMHO). I'm not new to C++ BTW. I'm very experienced but am just coming back from a long hiatus (a little rusty still but I immediately recognized the problem once Barry enlightened me).

Answer (score 2):

The range-based for expression you have:

```
for (int val : Test().GetCollection())
```

is equivalent to:

```
{
    auto&& __range = Test().GetCollection();  // (1)
    for ( auto __begin = begin(__range),      // (2)
          __end = end(__range);
          __begin != __end;
          ++__begin )
    {
        int val = *__begin;
        // etc
    }
}
```

`GetCollection()` returns a reference to `Test::_collection`, but that `Test` object goes out of scope at the end of the expression in line (1) - so you're left with a dangling reference by (2). Everything after that is just undefined behavior. It "working" is just one possible result of undefined behavior.

If `GetCollection()` instead looked like:

```
Collection GetCollection() const
^^^^^^^^^^^ by value
```

the lifetime of that temporary bound to a reference would get extended for the lifetime of the reference, which would be the entire range-based for expression. No undefined behavior in that scenario.